# Wordpress `Query No Results` block issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I use WordPress version 6.3.x with Full Site Editing enabled.
My Query Loop block has `No Results` block, but the problem is that when the query returns only 1 post, it shows both this post and the `No Results` block.

After some research, I've found [the issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/53772/files) and a fix to it in the Gutenberg repo, but I don't know how to apply it to my code as there are no hooks in this block.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it the correct way (avoiding change in the core files)? Maybe I'm missing some hooks that I can use? Or how can I apply a patch?

To be clear, I have no Gutenberg plugin installed, I use FSE out of the box as WordPress has it integrated into its codebase from version 6.

Answer (score 1):

As a work-around until the fix gets into WordPress core, consider having the `core/query-no-results` block *before* the `core/post-template` block:

```html
<!-- wp:query {…} -->
<div class="wp-block-query">
  <!-- wp:query-no-results -->
    <!-- wp:paragraph -->
    <p>No results</p>
    <!-- /wp:paragraph -->
  <!-- /wp:query-no-results -->

  <!-- wp:post-template {…} -->
    …
  <!-- /wp:post-template -->
</div>
<!-- /wp:query -->
```